# Loop through array of items using probability

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop, probability

I am pretty new to JavaScript and I have been making while-loops that rolls a dice and breaks out of the loop when you roll a 6.

```
var rollDice = function() {
  var dice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);

  while (dice !== 6) {
    console.log("A " + dice + " was rolled!");
    var dice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1)
  }
  console.log("Lucky! You rolled a 6!");
}
```

Now I want to loop through an array of items and break out of it when a desired item is found. I want to be able to declare the desired item like this:

```
var desiredItem = "Diamond";
```

However, every item has its own probability value that I would like to include in this while-loop. This would mean that you have a 25% chance of getting a rusty nail while only a 5% chance of receiving a diamond. So statistically you would be getting more rusty nails than diamonds. I also would like to output everything to the user inside the loop, like this:

```
console.log("Dang! A " + lootedItem + " was found...");
```

and when you finally receive the desired item and break out the loop:

```
console.log("Lucky! A" + desiredItem + "was found!");
```

I have been trying on my own for a while now but cant seem to get it, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an ES6 implementation for that:

```js
var findItem = function(desiredItem) {
    var items = [
        { item: "rusty nail", probability: 0.25 },
        { item: "stone", probability: 0.23 },
        { item: "banana", probability: 0.20 },
        { item: "leaf", probability: 0.17 },
        { item: "mushroom", probability: 0.10 },
        { item: "diamond", probability: 0.05 }
    ];
    var possible = items.some( ({item, probability}) => 
          item === desiredItem && probability > 0 );
    if (!possible) {
        console.log('There is no chance you\'ll ever find a ' + desiredItem);
        return;
    }
    var sum = items.reduce( (sum, {item, probability}) => sum+probability, 0 );
    while (true) {
        var value = Math.random() * sum;
        var lootedItem = items.find( 
                ({item, probability}) => (value -= probability) <= 0 ).item;
        if (lootedItem === desiredItem) break;
        console.log("Dang! A " + lootedItem + " was found...");
    }
    console.log("Lucky! A " + desiredItem + " was found!");
}

findItem('diamond');
```

Comment: this is a really cool answer!

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it has been very helpful!
Now I would like to add another value to the `items` array called `category? .
The categories can be either `2`, `5` or `10`.
So let's say the `diamond` item would belong to `category: 10`, and when I run `findItem` only items that belong to the same category are included in all the possibilities. I've tried for a few days now but can't seem to get it. Can anyone push me in the right direction? Thank you!

Comment: If you have a new question you should ask it as a newly created question. If you want me to have a look at it, you can post here a reference to it once you have created it. Anyway, I will be offline for the next 12 hours, so that is a second reason to post it as a new question: it will attract other people to it who will be able to help you with that. In the new question you can of course refer back to this one as those who answer want to use the code posted here.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've made another question now at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40002440/find-item-in-array-using-weighed-probability-and-a-value

Answer (score 0):

You could use the same approach for the diamond problem that you use in your dice while loop. Just generate a random number between 1-20, and if the number generated, for example, is 1, tell the user they've found a diamond since the odds of generating a 1 is 5%.

Answer (score 0):

A general answer allowing arbitrary weighted probabilities follows... I've used it with success in a few games I have written.

1. For each item, give it a positive probability. It does not need to be an
   integer, and they do not need to sum to 1.
2. Sum up all probabilities. Call it total.
3. Generate a number between 0 and Total, aka Math.random() * total
4. For each item, see if the number is less than the probability for that item. If it is, return that item. If, not subtract the probability, and go to the next item.

Answer (score 0):

```
const DIAMOND = 1,
      TRASH = 0;

var treasures = [DIAMOND, TRASH, TRASH, TRASH, DIAMOND],
    len = treasures.length;

function searchForDiamond() {
    while (true) {
        var j = Math.floor(getRandomArbitrary(0, len)),
            discovery = treasures[j];

        if (discovery === DIAMOND) {
            console.log("I am a lucky pirate!");
            break;
        } else {
            console.log("I am a crappy pirate!");
        }
    }
}

// FROM MDN
// Returns a random number between min (inclusive) and max (exclusive)
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}


searchForDiamond();
```