# Find item in array using weighed probability and a value

Tags: javascript, arrays, probability

Last week I had some problems with a simple program I am doing and somebody here helped me. Now I have run into another problem.
I currently have this code:

```js
var findItem = function(desiredItem) {
    var items = [
        { item: "rusty nail", probability: 0.25 },
        { item: "stone", probability: 0.23 },
        { item: "banana", probability: 0.20 },
        { item: "leaf", probability: 0.17 },
        { item: "mushroom", probability: 0.10 },
        { item: "diamond", probability: 0.05 }
    ];
    var possible = items.some( ({item, probability}) => 
          item === desiredItem && probability > 0 );
    if (!possible) {
        console.log('There is no chance you\'ll ever find a ' + desiredItem);
        return;
    }
    var sum = items.reduce( (sum, {item, probability}) => sum+probability, 0 );
    while (true) {
        var value = Math.random() * sum;
        var lootedItem = items.find( 
                ({item, probability}) => (value -= probability) <= 0 ).item;
        if (lootedItem === 'diamond') break;
        console.log("Dang! A " + lootedItem + " was found...");
    }
    console.log("Lucky! A " + desiredItem + " was found!");
}

findItem('diamond');
```

Now I would like to expand on this by adding another value called `category` to the `items` array. I want the categories to have a value of either `2`, `5` or `10`. So let's say the `diamond` item would belong to `category: 10`, and when `findItem` is executed only items that belong to the same category can be found. I have been trying for a couple of days now but can't seem to get my head around it. Maybe someone can help push me in the right direction? Thanks in advance

Comment: Use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to limit your search to the given category?

Comment: Do you mean with *can be found* that the "Dang! " message can only occur for that category and all other items should be completely ignored?

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it!

Comment: Yes trincot, that's exactly what I'm looking for! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this update to that code:

```js
// Pass the item list and the desired category as arguments:
var findItem = function(items, category, desiredItem) {
    // apply filter to items, so only those of the given category remain:
    items = items.filter( item => item.category == category );
    // rest of code remains the same:
    var possible = items.some( ({item, probability}) => 
          item === desiredItem && probability > 0 );
    if (!possible) {
        console.log('There is no chance you\'ll ever find a ' + desiredItem);
        return;
    }
    var sum = items.reduce( (sum, {item, probability}) => sum+probability, 0 );
    var t = 10;
    while (true) {
        var value = Math.random() * sum;
        var lootedItem = items.find( 
                ({item, probability}) => (value -= probability) <= 0 ).item;
        if (lootedItem === desiredItem) break; // fixed this condition!
        console.log("Dang! A " + lootedItem + " was found...");
        t--; if (t <= 0) throw "loop";
    }
    console.log("Lucky! A " + desiredItem + " was found!");
}

// Define items here with their category
var items = [
    { item: "rusty nail", probability: 0.25, category:  2 },
    { item: "stone",      probability: 0.23, category:  2 },
    { item: "banana",     probability: 0.20, category:  2 },
    { item: "leaf",       probability: 0.17, category:  5 },
    { item: "mushroom",   probability: 0.10, category:  5 },
    { item: "diamond",    probability: 0.05, category: 10 }
];

// Call function with extra arguments:
findItem(items, 5, 'mushroom');

console.log('second run:');
// This will obviously give a hit immediately, as there is only one possible item:
findItem(items, 10, 'diamond');
```

The changes are:

- Pass more arguments to your function: the items list and the desired category
- Apply a filter on the items list as first action in the function
- Fix an issue concerning the `lootedItem` test -- it had "diamond" hard-coded.
- Define the items list outside of the function and add category values to each element.
- Adapt the call of the function to pass the extra arguments.

Comment: Many thanks to you and thank you for explaining what every bit did. I feel like I know a bit more about coding now!

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this?

```js
var items = [ { item: "rusty nail", probability: 0.25, category: 10 }
            , { item: "stone",      probability: 0.23, category:  5 }
            , { item: "banana",     probability: 0.20, category:  2 }
            , { item: "leaf",       probability: 0.17, category:  5 }
            , { item: "mushroom",   probability: 0.10, category:  2 }
            , { item: "diamond",    probability: 0.05, category: 10 }
            ];

findItem("diamond", items);

function findItem(needle, haystack) {
    var item = haystack.find(thing => thing.item === needle &&
                                       thing.probability > 0);

    if (item) {
        var category = item.category;
        var items = haystack.filter(thing => thing.category === category);
        var sum = items.reduce((sum, thing) => sum + thing.probability, 0);

        var value = sum * Math.random();
        var loot = items.find(thing => (value -= thing.probability) <= 0).item;

        while (loot !== needle) {
            value = sum * Math.random();
            console.log("Dang! A " + loot + " was found...");
            loot = items.find(thing => (value -= thing.probability) <= 0).item;
        }

        return console.log("Lucky! A " + needle + " was found!");
    }

    console.log("There's no chance that you'll ever find a " + needle);
}
```

The only major difference from your code is that I used [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to limit the search.